# C# Binary Deserialization Error, class modification

Tags: c#, serialization, backwards-compatibility

(Please pardon my ability to efficiently describe this situation; I'm not a computer scientist or software engineer by trade. I'm just a GNC engineer that ends up doing a lot of coding)

I'm trying to load a binary serialization file that results in a load error.  There are class(es) that no longer exist in my program that (I believe) are causing this error.  Is there a general way to "ignore" that portion of the deserialization?

Perhaps this analogy will help:  I've got a file that describes how to build a bike, car, and airplane.  The guy who knows how to build all of those is gone, but the new guy knows how to build bikes and cars.  I'd like to give that file to the new guy to build me a bike and car, instead he throws a fit about not being able to build airplanes.  How can I tell this guy (call him Mr. Deserialize) to forget about the airplane and just build me my car and bike.

Thanks in advance,

(The ObjectManager found an invalid number of fixups. This usually indicates a problem in the Formatter)

Comment: Will the [`[NonSerialized]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute work to ignore the missing class?  Including any code would help narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a scenario where you need to implement `ISerializable`, and provide custom definition for `DeserializeItem` method. Example:

```
public class GNCEngineer : ISerializable
{
    public Bike Bike { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public Plane AirPlane { get; set; }

    public static void SerializeItem(string fileName, IFormatter formatter)
    { 
        // let serializer do their work 
    }

    public static void DeserializeItem(string fileName, IFormatter formatter)
    {
        // Ignore airplane and let rest work.
    }
}
```